# fork() is not working when trying to create new process

Tags: c

there is a tiny demo to test how semphore works. In main I using fork() to create producer and consumer child process which includes printf for wacthcing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFSIZE 10

static int buffer[BUFSIZE];
static int index = 0;
sem_t *empty;
sem_t *full;
sem_t *mutex;

void Producer(){
    for (int i = 0 ;i < 500; i++){
        sem_wait(empty);
        sem_wait(mutex);
        buffer[index++] = i;
        sem_post(mutex);
        sem_post(full);
    }
}

void Consumer(){
while(1){
        sem_wait(full);
        sem_wait(mutex);
        int temp = buffer[index--];
        sem_post(mutex);
        printf("%d\n",temp);
        sem_post(empty);
    }
}

int main(){
    empty = sem_open("empty",O_CREAT,0777,BUFSIZE);
    full = sem_open("full",O_CREAT,0777,0);
    mutex = sem_open("mutex",O_CREAT,0777,1);

    if(!fork()){
        printf("producer process........\n");
        Producer();
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if(!fork()){
                printf("consumer %d process........\n",i);
                Consumer();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
}
```

Here is the running result. It seems work, but no `printf("%d\n",temp);` in Consumer() output on screen. What's the reason? thx for your great help

```
consumer 6 process........
consumer 9 process........
consumer 7 process........
consumer 5 process........
consumer 8 process........
consumer 4 process........
consumer 3 process........
consumer 2 process........
consumer 1 process........
consumer 0 process........
producer process........
```

Comment: Please update question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: You're setting one process's `buffer` and `index`, and incorrectly expect that to that have an effect on the memory of other processes.

Comment: Previous comment identifies a *major* problem, but not the one you're asking about. I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm amazed at the complete lack of error checking. If things don't work, maybe that's the first thing you should do...

Comment: oh, is the problem that you only wait for one process when you should be waiting for 11?

Comment: The main issue is that you are leaving the semaphores in a bad state each time you run the program. These are named semaphores and will survive even after the processes terminate. So the processes are deadlocking. You need to explicitly `sem_unlink` to clean those up. Then there's the buffer index error which has already been identified.

Comment: A lesser issue is that `break` should be `return`. Otherwise all the child processes will incorrectly call `waitpid`.